# What is the max value that I can set for weight in NGINX upstream server configuration?

Tags: nginx, configuration, load-balancing

When configuring NGINX with multiple server entries, one can configure a round-robin algorithm for distributing load. 
NGINX offers the weight to indicate how weight is distributed. For ex.:

```
upstream backend {
 server backend1.example.com       weight=5;
 server backend2.example.com:8080  weight=1;

}
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

Question is: What is the maximum value assignable to weight?

My problem is that I have encountered a configuration with 2 server entries one with a weight value of 2000000000 (2 billion) and one with a value of 1. The intention was to have all traffic directed on the first server as temporarily the second one was down. However after far less than 2 bil requests users got error because they were directed to the second server.

Comment: Looking at the NGINX source code it seems that weight is of type ngx_int_t (https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/a6cb8210905f35977276cb3861184e4dad99cc2a/src/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_round_robin.h), so I'm assuming that means an int

Answer (score 1):

You should use health checking for that usage, not weight.

You have 2 options:

1. Using built in nginx layer 3 healthchecks:

   `Using max_fails`, `fail_timeout` and even `backup` directive.

   `backup`: marks the server as a backup server. It will be passed requests when the primary servers are unavailable.
2. Using community modules like [nginx_upstream_check_module](https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_upstream_check_module)

   This module enables layer 7 healthchecks, This is the recommended way.

Comment: Thanks Farhad, I've actually used the backup option, but was curious to learn the actual limit for the weight param. I wanted to give a comprehensive explanation to my stakeholders regarding the cause of the errors we got. Telling them that we went over the 2 billion requests limit in 2 days is not going to fly :-)